# Silverlight Enabled WCF - Error implementing the service-Reg

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I request for help on silverlight enabled WCF.

I get following error while implementing WCF in Silverlight.

```
"An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:4496/PROJECT/Service.svc'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details"
```

I am using Silver Enabled WCF Template.

When checked with Fiddler it is found that 404 ERROR  is displayed for 
1.clientaccesspolicy.xml
2.crossdomain.xml

Clientaccesspolicy.xml Contains following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Crossdomain.xml contains following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: To troubleshoot your issue. Where have you created the service, is it in the .web project where your silverlight application is hosted?

Comment: Dear,  Instead adding .xml files at .web project, I have added them to silver light application.

Answer (score 0):

zafar thanks for responding.

Instead of adding .xml files at .web project, I have added them to silver light aplication. For the present problem solved.

There is one more problem:

Every time my computer is rebooted, I get weird error from service

```
Could not load file or assembly App_Web_yadayadayada
```

"yadayadayada" is the assembly file created every time web application is run through visual studio.

For this there is a solution at[Here](http://creative-jar.com/insights/digital-technology/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app_web_/)

The following attribute is added to web.config

```
<compilation debug=”false” batch=”false”>
```

For the present it is working.

**The second problem is**

Kindly help me this problem.

The design part of silverlight is visible only in Chrome browser and it is half visible in IE and not visible in firefox. Please help.

The Design main.xaml is furnished below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My_silverlight.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1000" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit">
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Name="busyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" >


    <Grid x:Name="layoutRoot" ShowGridLines="True"  Height="900" Width="950" Background="Orange">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="PROJECT" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
Grid.RowSpan="2"></TextBlock>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Background="White" Margin="0,27,0,7" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="256*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="255" />
                <RowDefinition Height="205" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Name of the Pilgrim :" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green" Margin="4,10,-14,4"  ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="About Me :" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green" Margin="4,10,-14,4"  ></TextBlock>
            <!--<TextBlock Text="Country :" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green" Margin="4,10,-14,4"  ></TextBlock>-->
            <TextBox Text="K" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green" Height="30" ></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="SharePoint Developer" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green"  Height="30"  ></TextBox>
            <!--<TextBox Text="India" FontFamily="Verdana" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green"  Height="30"   ></TextBox>-->

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="start" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"   />
                    <Button Content="capture" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"   />
                </StackPanel>

                <Rectangle x:Name="rectWebCamView" Width="200" Height="200"  Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                <Image Height="170" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="22,50,0,30"  />
                <Image Height="170" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="22,50,0,30"  />
                <Image Height="170" Name="image3" Stretch="Fill" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="22,50,0,30"  />
                <Image Height="170" Name="image4" Stretch="Fill" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="22,50,0,30"  />


            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
                <Image Height="170" Name="image5" Stretch="Fill" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,50,0"  />
                <Image Height="170" Name="image6" Stretch="Fill" Width="150"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  />

            </StackPanel>


            <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />




        </Grid>
    </Grid>



</toolkit:BusyIndicator>
    <!--<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>-->
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It's working fine now. At the time of embedding silverlight object, I have size of the object as 100%. The issue may please be treated as closed.